# How can i start process inside another function in python?

Tags: python, function, process, multiprocessing

Suppose i have two functions

```
def funct1():
    ##does something
def funct2():
    ##does something
```

I want to use them in another function with multiprocessing like so:

```
def my_funct
    ##does something
    if __name__ == '__main__':
         p1 = Process(target = funct1)
         p2 = Process(target = funct2)
         p1.start()
         p2.start()
         ##more code
         p1.terminate()
         p2.terminate()
     return something
```

Basically i want to start and end processes inside my function but its not working properly. What would be the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

On platforms that use the *spawn* method to create new processes it becomes necessary to place the process-creation code that exists *at the global scope* within an `if __name__ == '__main__':` block to prevent the newly created child process from trying to re-execute recursively the process-creation code since *all code* at the global level is re-executed in order to initialize memory (e.g. function definitions and global variables) for the process. Putting such a test within a function or method, which by definition would not be at global scope, would not normally make too much sense.

In your case there must be some code in the main script being executed (where `__name__` would be `'__main__'` unless that script is launched as a module with the **-m** Python flag) that invokes directly or indirectly your `my_funct` function. It is that code that should be placed in a `if __name__ == '__main__':` block. For example:

```py
def my_funct
    ##does something
    p1 = Process(target = funct1)
    p2 = Process(target = funct2)
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    ##more code
    p1.terminate()
    p2.terminate()
    return something

def function main():
    # Do some work
    ...
    # Call my_funct, which creates new child processes:
    print(my_funct())
    # Do some more work
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # The following function invocation is at global scope in the main script 
    # and invokes code that will ultimately be creating new child processes:
    main()
```

If the `if __name__ == '__main__':` test were instead moved to where you had it originally, then function `main` would be invoked as part of the initialization of memory for the new processes that were created in function `my_funct`. But I am sure you would not want `main` or any part of `my_funct` to be re-executed, which would happen with this move.

**Note**

I should add that *any* code at global scope that you do not want or do not need to be re-executed as part of memory initialization for the new child process should be placed within a `if __name__ == '__main__':` block , not just process-creation code. Also note that if your `my_funct` is imported from some module, then `__name__` would not be `'__main__'` to begin with.